# Visited links have no style on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css, mobile

This seems to have started following the spate of code changes associated with the new close-vote and duplicate banners. Visited links on mobile are unstyled now:

[image]

That freehand-circled sentence is a link, but I only knew it from context since I'd just visited it from the main page. I'm pretty sure visited links "disappearing" like this is not an intended feature.

Comment: I see them subtly styled red (no underline or anything) on iPhone 4S.

Comment: Oh wait no you're right - proper links are decorated but auto question links are not.

Comment: Just checked: It's not just the auto question links. Unvisited links have the subtle red styling (subtle, but not so subtle that it's not immediately obvious as a link), but if you click one (I just checked by following the link to your character sheets from [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22173/what-to-do-when-your-character-is-just-too-good)), then when you use the Back putton and/or refresh, the now-visited link gets no colour or decoration.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167823/can-the-color-of-visited-links-be-changed-on-the-mobile-site

Comment: Marking status-completed because it's noted as fixed in the main meta question.

Comment: @mxyzplk Can anyone confirm that RPG's design is in fact fixed like the main meta?

Comment: @GraceNote Confirmed!

Comment: @gracenote confirmed by me too

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed, [as per this Meta Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167823/can-the-color-of-visited-links-be-changed-on-the-mobile-site/168979#168979). There was an error in the CSS that has (long, eheh) since been fixed.